# Email Results of Dynamic Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

```
*****EDIT*****

The problem resulted from using a temp table. Therefore this post was marked as a duplicate.
```

I wrote a query that dynamically selects columns for a Pivot. The query works fine when I execute it like so `EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery`

The dynamic pivot looks like this (it works):

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumnNames AS nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotSelectColumnNames AS nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumnNames = UPPER(ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','') 
                           + QUOTENAME(CSR)) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CSR FROM #stats) AS CSRs
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames = 
                                 UPPER(ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
                                 + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(CSR) + ', 0) AS '
                                 + QUOTENAME(CSR))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CSR FROM #stats) AS CSRs

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT Category, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
FROM #stats 
PIVOT (
    MAX([COUNT])
    FOR CSR IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) as PivotTable'
```

I want to email these results as part of a SQL Server Agent Job.

When I execute the sp_send_dbmail like below it throws an error:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='donotreply'
,@recipients ='****@****.com'
,@query= @DynamicPivotQuery
,@subject= 'Weekly Stats for New Sales, Winbacks, and TPV by Reps'
,@attach_query_result_as_file=1
,@query_attachment_filename='Customer Service Report.csv'
,@query_result_separator=',' --enforce csv
,@query_result_no_padding=1 --trim
,@query_result_width=32767  --stop wordwrap
```

Here is the error it throws:

```
Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server CV-SQL2012\CVOSSQL, Line 1
Invalid object name '#stats'.
```

I've tried executing the email SP with a simpler query in place of @DynamicPivotQuery and it worked.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the `sendmail` in the same dynamic context that creates the temp table.

That or switch to either a global temp table or a permanent table.

Comment: Wow I did not think it would be that simple. I changed it to a global temp table and it worked first try. I thought something else was going on. Thanks a bunch.